# What's the best stack exchange site to ask about web development career questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The particular question in mind is "Is it common for people hiring for JavaScript programmers to mistakenly say Java", with a few specific examples of where I think the mistake has been made. I often have career-related questions and don't know which site is the preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

First piece of advice; whatever site you go to, visit their help center and check what is on-topic *before* asking your question.

That said, a properly phrased question of that type would likely be on-topic at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) which covers hiring practices/interviews. Here is their on-topic rules: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic